# Starting process as NETWORK SERVICE

Tags: c#

I am trying to start a process with user NETWORK SERVICE, from a service running under LOCAL SYSTEM. To do this I am using the following sequence of pinvoke operations:

1. `LogonUser()`
2. `DuplicateTokenEx()`
3. `LoadUserProfile()`
4. `CreateEnvironmentBlock()`
5. `CreateProcessAsUser()`

Using the steps above I was able to get the process to launch - I see the process creation event in the event viewer. However the process I am creating is a C# application that spawns a conhost.exe child process and crashes immediately due possibly to the conhost.exe child process crashing (also shows up in the event log - the crash reason is DLL initialization failure).

I have also found that if I give NETWORK SERVICE administrator privileges on my machine, I am able to use the steps above to start the process successfully.

Finally, I have also tried launching the same process directly from a service running under the NETWORK SERVICE user, and in that case it starts successfully. This makes me suspect that something about the context in which I am trying to start the new process is incomplete and I am missing another operation to prime the environment.

Is there anything obviously wrong with my approach? Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: Focus on the file access error. Network Service account might not have access to the necessary files, and you can use Process Monitor to check which files and then determine whether you would like to change the file NTFS permissions to allow access.

Comment: I have tried this previously and do not see any immediately suspicious Access Denied errors. Also, since a service running under Network Service is able to successfully start this process directly via Process.Start(), the question is how does it do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was incorrect setting of the `lpDesktop` field of `STARTUP_INFO` structure. If the value is not set to `string.Empty`, the new process will attempt to use the desktop of the parent process, which it does not have access to.